# Is there a way to use gradle to obfuscate code for minecraft 1.8.9?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am coding a minecraft mod and when I run it in forge 1.8.9 I get the `noSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.client.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj`. However, when I run another mod, that one works.

My mod's decompiled class file looks like

```
this.renderer = Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj;
```

while the other one looks like

```
this.renderer = Minecraft.func_71410_x().field_71466_p;
```

No matter how I build my mod, my class files never end up looking like this. How do I make gradle obfuscate the code?

Comment: What Gradle command are you running?

Comment: I first ran the setupDecompWorkspace command, then the build command to get the jar.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right jar? `./gradlew build` should already produce a jar that works with obfuscated names.

Answer (score -2):

One option is to use Gradle in order to load ProGuard and obfuscate your JAR using it.

Your then require a dependency such as this:

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
     }
     
     dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.1.1'
     }
}
```

You also need to define a task, similar to this:

```
task useProGuard (type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguardcfg.pro'
    injars  jar.archivePath
    outjars "${myDir}/MyJar.jar"
}
```

And as shown in the task create a proguard configuration file, where you define rules as to what ProGuard is supposed to do and what classes should be processed.

Entries in this file can look like this:

```
#-dontobfuscate
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-keep class com.jni.** { *; }
...
```

Where the commented out parameter is a command to prevent obfuscation, the next two commands are telling ProGuard not to shrink the JAR or use their own optimiztion and the last entry is a rule for classes in a package called `com.jni`, as it is dangerous to change function signatures of `native` functions.

---

Read more on ProGuard:

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples

In addition I believe the standard Android build pipeline also uses ProGuard by default.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to obfuscate his own methods. He wants it to be rewritten to be compatible with Minecraft's obfuscated method names, so it works outside of a development environment.

Comment: *He wants it to be rewritten* - what exaclty is "it"?

Comment: His mod jar references a bunch of fields and methods that exist in Minecraft's own code. One is `fontRendererObj`. But only people who download a mod development environment get a version of Minecraft with that field name. Regular players instead have an obfuscated version of Minecraft where that field is called `field_71466_p`. He's asking how to make his mod's jar file use the obfuscated field names, so it will work for regular players. Usually, `./gradlew build` just does this for you with Minecraft mods, so the question here is why it didn't for him.

Comment: I see. My solution is only tailored to obfuscate their JAR and define a scheme such as the one used. But it will not do any mapping of course, if this is required then the minecraft functions need to be obfuscated together with the mod, otherwise mapping is impossible.

Comment: "mapping is impossible" It is not. That's literally how every single Forge mod works.

Comment: How is mapping done, when obfuscating the codebases independently?

Comment: I don't know exactly how they do it, but having made mods myself with ForgeGradle before, I know they do it somehow.